# What is the recommended way to apply CRUD operations to a document in Cloud Firestore using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking into migrating a large application written in Xamarin and moving to Flutter with **Cloud Firestore** as the backend. Since Cloud Firestore is still in beta there appears to be very few **concrete examples** demonstrating best practices when called from a Flutter client.

In particular - there seems to be no direct approach to checking whether a TX has failed or whether it succeeds.

So taking the standard '**Delete**' operation as an example - what is the best approach to rolling your own transactions within both online/offline mode including providing appropriate error handling in Flutter  ?

I have expanded on my solution below **(in the remove method)** and you can see that two network calls are being made, one to get the latest document reference and another to perform the delete.

However, since we use a StreamBuilder that gets updates to when any documents change , can we not positively assume that **widget.documents[index].reference** will hold the latest document reference and therefore do away with :

```
var snapshot=await tx.get(docReference)
if (snapshot.exists){
    await tx.delete(snapshot.reference)
}
```

and just use :

```
   var docReference = widget.documents[index].reference;
   await tx.delete(docReference);
```

**Note**

Both of the approaches above work - i am after an approach that conforms 100% to ACID test in relation to transactions as well as offering best performance.

**Example use case**

Streambuilder subscription:

[image: Streambuilder subscription]

In the `FirestoreListView` a `ListView.Builder` is created that adds delete/edit button that allows any item to be deleted or added , thus we have something like this :

Listview:

[image: Listview]

Behind the delete button, we perform the delete as :

Delete code:

[image: Delete code]

Comment: Personally I would do it without the transaction, we already have the document reference. I don't see any critical issues that `widget.documents[index].referece.delete()` would cause. If the delete goes into problems, the same `try` `catch` approach can handle the error.